# NPM Cannot read property 'algorithm' of undefined

Tags: npm

This error message is displayed when using `npm publish` with tarball (tgz) file.

```
npm publish my-lib.tgz
```

npm version: 5.5.1

**Results on:**

npm ERR! Cannot read property 'algorithm' of undefined 
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: 
npm ERR! C:\npm\cache_logs\2018-02-07T01_35_30_633Z-debug.log 
[object Object]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution in this case was to upgrade the version from npm to 5.6.

Comment: In VSTS this also is a problem. Follow https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/issues/6377